# ajax request triggered but success function won't start until I stop the page

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, forms, progress-bar

The server I'm developing on is the Django 1.4 development server on Open-SUSE.

### My Problem

My jquery ajax request is triggered, but the success function does not run until I stop the page with my browser.

### What I've tried

I've set up flags all over the place to track the progress of the ajax function. Everything is working correctly, but the success function does not run until I stop the page. Here's my JS:

```
var submitted = '';
var freq =3000; // freqency of update in ms
var counter = 0;

$('#webfileuploadform').submit(function(){

    $(document).ajaxSend(function(){
        console.log("Triggered ajaxsend handler.")
    });

    if(submitted == 'submitted') return false; // prevents multiple submits
    var progress_url = '/upload_progress/' + $('#id_progress_id').val(); // ajax view serving progress info
    var progress_guid = $('#id_progress_id').val();
    this.action += (this.action.indexOf('?') == -1 ? '?' : '&') + 'X-Progress-ID=' + progress_guid;

    var $progress = $('<div id="upload-progress" class="upload-progress"></div>').appendTo($('#webfileuploadform')).append('<div class="progress-container"><div class="progress-info">uploading 0%</div><div class="progress-bar"></div></div>');

    function update_progress_bar(){
        console.log("update_progress_bar() was hit");
        $progress.show();
        $.ajax({
            dataType:"json",
            url: progress_url,
            beforeSend: function(){
                console.log('before send');
            },
            success: function(data){
                //debugger;
                if(data.status == "uploading"){
                    var total_progress = parseInt(data.uploaded) / parseInt(data.length);
                    var width = $progress.find('.progress-container').width();
                    var progress_width = width * total_progress;
                    $progress.find('.progress-bar').width(progress_width);
                    $progress.find('.progress-info').text('uploading ' + parseInt(total_progress*100) + '%');
                    counter++;
                    console.log("status: " + data.status + counter);
                    //console.log("data.length " + data.length);
                    //console.log("data.uploaded " + data.uploaded);
                    //console.log("progress_width " + progress_width + '\n');
                } else if (data.status == "not-found") {
                    clearTimeout(progress_bar_updater);
                    console.log("status = not-found");
                } else {
                    clearTimeout(progress_bar_updater);
                    console.log("data.status = " + data.status);
                }
            },
            error: function(textStatus){
                console.log("ERROR: " + textStatus);
            },
            complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus){
                console.log(textStatus);
            }
        });
        var progress_bar_updater = setTimeout(function(){update_progress_bar()}, freq);
    }

    window.setTimeout(function(){update_progress_bar()}, freq);

    submitted = 'submitted'; // marks form as submitted

});
```

You can see all my flags. I use my form to select a file to upload, I submit the form, and the console reads as follows:

```
update_progress_bar() was hit
before send
Triggered ajaxsend handler.
```

So this means my function containing the ajax call is being triggered, and so is the ajax request because the the beforeSend and ajaxSend functions both output their contents. Also note, the error function did not output anything so there wasn't a problem. Now the weird part. I press the stop button in Chrome and the console output now returns this:

```
update_progress_bar() was hit
before send
Triggered ajaxsend handler.
status: uploading1
success
```

So now, after the page was stopped, the entire ajax function runs without error. The success function outputs to the console and so does the complete function. The error function still output nothing.

Because of the setTimeout I have called inside the function, it iterates until I refresh the page (or, depending on how long after I pressed submit and then pressed stop in the browser, it has read all the temporary data from the django file upload handler) outputting to the console each time until it finally outputs "not-found" (which is the end of the file).

### What I'm trying to accomplish

My form is for users to upload large files to the server. I want a progress bar to prevent users from thinking that the browser froze and then re-load the files. The progress bar works just fine after I stop the page. The background and "uploading 0%" all increment as they should. But just not until I stop the page.

It should increment as the file is being read by the server. Why isn't it?

Comment: The submit handler needs to return `false` to prevent normal form submission.

Comment: I'd suggest using the xhr.upload.onprogress and xhr.onprogress events for browsers that support it, then defaulting to an indeterminate progressbar for older browsers.

Comment: @Barmar I put a return false in the handler, but that did not solve it. The form won't process anything at all if I do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the ajax function I set the async setting to false:

```
$.ajax({
    async: false,
    ...
});
```

This has solved the problem. I have no idea how. From what I understand, this setting forces the ajax request to wait until all other http requests are finished before allowing it to continue. With that being the case, I have no idea how this works. I'll keep from answering my own question in case someone knows why this is working this way...